# Call to a member function bind_param() - What's wrong?

Tags: php

Please, someone save me from this burning pit of death. I'm literally pulling my hair out here.

**Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in path on line 8**

Thanks

```
<?php

    include 'admin/db_connect.php';

    $result;

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `latitude`,`longitude` FROM ? WHERE `route` = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $company, $route);

    $company = $_GET['company'];
    $company .= "_routes";
    $route = $_GET['route'];

    $stmt->execute();
    $statement->bind_result($result);

    printf($result);

?>
```

**db_connect.php:**

```
define("HOST", "");
define("USER", "");
define("PASSWORD", "");
define("DATABASE", "");

$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
```

Comment: Typo: `$stmt->bind_result($result);`

Comment: What does your `db_connect` look like?  Are you initializing mysqli as an object or a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You encountered an error, thats why false is returned, which is not an object, which leads to this error.

Have a look at whats in  `$mysqli->error` right after "prepare"

Is your connection up?

it is not possible to have the table name dynamic in prepared statements.

It is only intended for parameters, i guess thats your error.
prepared statement is for the column values not for table name.

you have to build your query without prepared statements.

Comment: Thanks! The $mysqli->error returned a problem with the connection.